# Why is reat-admin not getting undefined exceptions for not-loaded record (e.g. Poster component)?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am looking at react-admin demo code trying to learn from it. I have noticed quite a few time the same behavior:  demo code is not waiting for a `record` to load and does not get undefined exceptions. I am struggling to understand why are they not getting the undefined exception. For example: In `PosterEdit` [source code](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/products/ProductEdit.js) they are just using the  component which looks like

```
const Poster = ({ record }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent className={classes.content}>
                <img src={record.image} alt="" className={classes.img} />
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

If I use the component in the same way, I get undefined exception

```
TypeError: can't access property "image", record is undefined
```

I do not understand the magic from the demo code. Can someone demystify?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for this exact example.

My Poster component was placed within several `Grid` components from material-u. Here is the cleaned code sample to show the structure.

```
<Edit {...props} aside={<Aside />}>
      <TabbedForm }>
        <FormTab >

          <Grid container fullWidth className={classes.tabContent}>
            <Grid item xs={7}>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom className={classes.sectionTitle}/>
                     <Poster 

                </Grid>
             </Grid>   
           </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </FormTab >
         ..other form tabs..
       </TabbedForm }>
</Edit>
```

If the component is placed directly as `FormTab` child, then it works. I still do not understand why though. Anyway, I hope it helps someone.